# Lebesgue outer measure is countably subadditive but not finitely additive proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have read all the Qs on this but couldn't find a clear proof.
How can I prove that Lebesgue's outer measure is not finitely additive?
Thanks!

Edit: I understand I must show that the measure of the union of sets is infinite, but the sets have all finite measure.
I am in $R$ so I was thinking something along the lines of $R$ \ $Q$ and $Q$, since $R$ \ $Q$ can be partitioned in [$i$, $i+1$] intervals, but then this also works for $R$ so I'm not sure this works.

Comment: It follows from a somewhat circuitous argument: There exist non-measurable sets, so $\exists E, X \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $m^{\ast}(X) \neq m^{\ast}(E\cap X) + m^{\ast}(E^c\cap X)$. Now $E\cap X$ and $E^c\cap X$ are the two sets that violate finite additivity.

Comment: But how do I know there exists non-measurable sets? Maybe the outer measure could be exactly the same as the Lebesgue measure, everywhere, and therefore be a measure, if I don't prove it's not finitely additive, am I wrong?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I've added some thoughts in my original quetsion

Comment: Existence of non-measurable sets (ie. a set $E$ that violates the Caratheodory condition mentioned above) follows from an application of the axiom of choice. A good place to look is Royden's book on Real Analysis. Fact is, the outer measure *does not* extend to a measure on the power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Oh is it the Vitali set?